# How to Change access level of WebSphere Application Server (read only) profile

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am trying to configure WebSphere Application Server 8.5 beta on Rational Application Developer. 
In the WebSphere Application Server settings, profile name drop down list is coming empty, though profiles are already created in WebSphere Application Server. When I click on configure profile on WAS Server settings, all profile under WebSphere Application Server profiles defined in the runtime are coming as "read-only". that means I dont have permission to manage profiles for the server, as I am a non-root user with read-only access to the installations. I am working on Windows 7 (x64) with Administrative privileges.

I am following this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tpro_rootpro_nonroot_own.html)

But no luck.

Can anybody help me out here , How can the access level of server be changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When launching RAD, right-click on the icon and choose "Run as administrator". You can set the  properties of the shortcut to always run as administrator.

Comment: Thank you Svachon, it did work out. I also created profiles out of c:\program files(x86) location, it's also working fine.